# Как будет слово "мечта" в множественном числе?

Tags: грамматика

Здравствуйте!

Как пишется и произносится слово "мечта" в множественном числе?

Спасибо.

Comment: МечтЫ. Как пишется, так и произносится. А вас интересуют косвенные падежи? Укажите, какие.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Все тут:
[мечта | ru.wiktionary.org](http://ru.wiktionary.org/wiki/%D0%BC%D0%B5%D1%87%D1%82%D0%B0)

Если что-то непонятно, спрашивайте. Только конкретно.

Comment: Т.е. сказать можно написать/сказать: "У меня есть много мечт"?

Comment: Владислав, можно подумать/сказать/написать : "У меня есть много мечт, но ни одного пальта...", однако проделывать такие фокусы на экзаменах в Российской Федерации - не рекомендуется)

Comment: >>Т.е. сказать можно написать/сказать: "У меня есть много мечт"?  
  
Если вы про нормативность варианта, то нет. Но эта ненормативность носит чисто фонетический характер. Вариант мечт легко восстанавливается и не используется только из-за труднопроизносимости. Грамматических запретов тут нет.

Comment: Действительно, слова с тем же "окончанием" **чта** - мачта и почта - совершенно свободно употребляются в литературе и обычной речи в Р.п. : высоких мачт, министр почт... Чтобы стали спокойно говорить *много мечт*, надо какому-нибудь большому-большому писателю-поэту дать запоминающийся удачный образец выражения с мечтами в Р.п. Народ подхватит и дело пойдет на лад. Наверное, лучше использовать форму проникновенного романса : "В моей душе так много мечт...", ну и тд.

Comment: Спасибо!!!

Comment: Тоже не один раз слышала вариант "мечт". Когда говорю, что такого слова нет все смеются, т.к. воспринимается оно совершенно нормально.